# How to update chart js in Vue app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some chart and I want to update it via clicking a button. Data changes in the store but UI doesn't update.

```
<div class="graph">               
  <button class="click" @click="changeUi">Change chart</button>                
  <canvas id="mix" count="2"></canvas>
  <chartjs-line target="mix"></chartjs-line>
  <chartjs-bar :option="{legend: { display: false }}" 
  :labels="mylabels":datasets="mydatasets" target="mix"></chartjs-bar>
</div>
 export default {
 data(){
   return{
     mydatasets:[{   
       data: this.$store.state.data}], //This data i want to change
       //data: [20, 50, 20, 41, 26, 15, 20, 10, 29, 5, 33, 55]
     methods:{
       changeUi(){
             this.$store.commit('changeChart')
             // I want change by this array [10, 30, 34, 23, 11, 15, 55, 30, 19, 35, 43, 21]
        }
    }
}
```

I am importing chart in main.js  :

```
  import 'chart.js'
  import 'hchs-vue-charts'
  Vue.use(window.VueCharts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Store properties should be used as `computed` property in your components, not inside `data()`.